# cocoa get sheet state

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, state, cocoa-sheet

Is there a way to determine the state of a sheet? I know I can call this method:

```
- (void) customSheetDidClose : (NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

but what I want to do is something like this:

```
- (void) getInfoMethod { 

    //...do a lot of stuff to gather data

    [self openSheetMethod:dictionaryFullOfStuff];


    //I am completely making this up
    while([panFileDataEditor state] == open) { 
        //do nothing
    } 

}

- (void) openSheetMethod : (NSDictionary*) stuff { 

    //...do something with stuff

    [NSApp beginSheet: panFileDataEditor modalForWindow: window modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(customSheetDidClose:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];

}
```

I'm using a NSPanel for my sheet, I was thinking I could get its frame and check the y location to determine its status but I wanted to check to see if there was an accepted way of doing this...

Comment: I reworded the question on google and got this: BOOL hasSheet = ([window attachedSheet] != nil);

Comment: I reworded the question on google and got this: BOOL hasSheet = ([window attachedSheet] != nil);, changed my code to this: while([winMain attachedSheet] != nil) { 
    NSLog(@"the sheet is open");
   } but I then can't do anything in the sheet itself

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL hasSheet = ([window attachedSheet] != nil);
```

is only meant to test whether the sheet exists; [`-[NSWindow attachedSheet]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIJGGAC) will return the sheet if it's there, or `nil` if not. I'm not clear on what "state" you're trying to get, but

```
NSWindow * theSheet = [window attachedSheet];
```

does give you the sheet itself. From there you can do whatever you like: `[theSheet frame]`, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa is an event based system so you don't wait for things to happen in a while loop, instead methods you write are called by the system when things happen. So no while loops.

You implement the customSheetDidClose:returnCode:contextInfo: method (not call it) in your class and it will be called when the sheet closes.

If you want custom things to happen when the sheet is open create a subclass of NSWindowController to handle the sheet.